# MIDI recording from keyboard and editing on Android

Tags: android, music, music-production, music-composing, midi

I've got a micro USB to OTG adapter to USB-B with which I can connect my Android tablet to a Casio keyboard.  On some apps such as WalkBand I can play on the keyboard and the app receives the MIDI events and plays them in the app as well, and can even record them.

However, at this point I want to actually do something with the MIDI notes besides just be able to play them.  I want to see them on a piano roll, and maybe even as sheet music, and be able to from the piano roll edit, either to move notes around, adjust the length, snap them to the appropriate 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc. (this would be a batch operation) as well as add and remove notes.

Can be free or for pay.

Comment: This is called a MIDI sequencer.

Comment: Not tried myself, but take a look at [Audio Evolution](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.aemobiledemo) (link to the free trial). Its [full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.aemobile) is available for ~EUR 7.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how much the in-app store charges for MIDI support?  It's confusing that you would have to pay more for this after already paying $7 for the "full version".

Comment: No idea, unfortunately – as I wrote, I've never tried it myself. Maybe approaching the dev?

Comment: @Izzy seem to have some issues editing as well... the documentation isn't matching what I am seeing (for editing it shows a different color scheme, and I can't seem to select or edit notes in edit mode).